# How to put .setTitle parameter for Button in the UserDefaults and in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, button, swift4, userdefaults, swiftyuserdefaults

Maybe someone of you know how to put `clearButton.setTitle` parameter in the `UserDefaults` and after that put to override `func viewDidLoad() {`

That's parameters which i'm try to put before `viewDidLoad` to prepare a key, but i think  `defaults.set` is incorrect

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let clearB = "clearB"

clearButton.setTitle("Clear", for: .normal )

defaults.set(clearButton.setTitle, forKey: clearB).
```

Thank you for your help
BR
Ula

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Do you want to change the title for your button?

Comment: I'm trying to save Label of the button after application will be closed, because there is two versions of the text for this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let clearB = "clearB"
clearButton.setTitle("Clear", for: .normal )

UserDefaults.standard.set(clearButton.titleLabel!.text, forKey: clearB)
```

Retrieve:

```
if let title = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: clearB) {
    clearButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's answer which i'm expected but strange that if i'm closing the application after changes of title and open again Title of the button still the same like on start it's not saving previous changes but others like example labels saving changes correct. Maybe you can advise what  can be the reason?

Comment: Fixed . Found the problem. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Good. Glad to help!